# Testing with spring security not checking roles

Tags: spring-security, spring-data-jpa, automated-tests

I have experience with springframework and boot but not so much with spring security.

I have a test that I am running but the failure test succeeds.

I have listed:

- The *service* in case I have missed something
- The security configuration incase I have borked that
- The test case itself, tho it is pretty simple
- The maven dependencies incase there is a missing starter

Service:

```
@Service
public class BuildingService {

    private final BuildingRepository repo;

    public BuildingService(final BuildingRepository repo) {
        this.repo = repo;
    }

    @Secured({RolesConst.MANAGING_AGENT, RolesConst.BACK_OFFICE})
    public Page<Building> getAll(final Pageable pageable) {
        return repo.findAll(pageable);
    }

    @Secured({RolesConst.MANAGING_AGENT, RolesConst.BACK_OFFICE})
    public Optional<Building> getById(final String id) {
        return repo.findById(id);
    }

    @Secured({RolesConst.MANAGING_AGENT, RolesConst.BACK_OFFICE})
    public Building save(final Building building) {
        return repo.save(building);
    }
}
```

Configuration for spring security:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class ServiceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MongoTransactionManager transactionManager(MongoDatabaseFactory dbFactory) {
        return new MongoTransactionManager(dbFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf()
                .disable()
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                .anyRequest().authenticated())
            .httpBasic();

        return http.build();
    }

}
```

Test:

```
    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username = "bob", password = "password", authorities = {"TENANT"})
    public void givenValidTent_whenAccessRestrictedResource_thenFailWith401() throws Exception {
        final ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("payloads/successful-create-building.json");
        final String payload = Files.readString(Path.of(resource.getURI()));

        // Create building
        mvc.perform(post("/building")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(payload))
                .andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
    }
```

Pom test deps:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Edit 1:

- spring boot 3.0.5
- Java 20

Edit 2:

Tried adding the following to the test case but yields the same failure

```
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private MockMvc mvc;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context)
                    .apply(springSecurity()) 
                    .build();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The configuration was fine, however the values I had in RoleConst were: ROLE_MA, so I need to use *hasAnyAuthority* instead of anyRole